# egrep and grep "matching-pattern" followed by "non-matching-pattern" with regular expression linux

Tags: grep

How to find matching-pattern followed by non-matching-pattern in `grep` or `egrep`?

Have a file script.txt with entries as below. I would like search for lines matching-pattern followed by non-matching pattern Eg: I would like to get last three lines but not first two.

```
/script/upgrade/pre_somefile.sql
/script/upgrade/pre_someotherfile.sql
/script/upgrade/anotherfile.sql
/script/upgrade/yetanotherfile.sql
/script/pre_deploy/yetanotherfile.sql
```

I tried using regular expression similar to below in egrep but no luck.

[image]

Tried below in egrep

```
egrep "/script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/(?!pre).*" script.txt
```

If use `-v` option then last line is not getting picked.

```
egrep "/script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/" script.txt | egrep -v "pre"
```

Any idea how to implement regex for this case in egrep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With grep -E/egrep (the same thing), you can do:

```
grep -E '/script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/' script.txt |
    grep -E -v '/script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/pre_'
```

or if your grep has the -P option:

```
grep -P 'script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/(?!pre)' script.txt
```

from the man page:

```
 -P, --perl-regexp
      Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).
      This   is   highly   experimental   and   grep   -P   may   warn   of
      unimplemented features.
```

But this last one isn't good for production code.

Comment: Thanks Ronaldo `grep -P` is OK, just curious `egrep -P` does not work and has some conflict with regex pattern

Comment: `egrep` is exactly the same thing as `grep -E`, than, `egrep -P` is `grep -E -P` and both will produce a error message like `grep: conflicting matchers specified`. A better alternative to `grep -P` might be `pcregrep` if available.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'match($0,"/script/(upgrade|pre_deploy)/") && substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)!~/pre/' file
/script/upgrade/anotherfile.sql
/script/upgrade/yetanotherfile.sql
/script/pre_deploy/yetanotherfile.sql
```